# Couting this char sequence giving errors (beginner)

Tags: c++, char

I get many errors, along the lines of ... std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits> etc ... What's wrong with this code? Also, I'm avoiding using strings for a reason, I have to use chars.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cassert>

using namespace std;

void x(char y) {

  char z = toupper(y);
  if (z == 'A')
        cout << 'G' << 'C' << 'T' << '\n' << 'G' << 'C' << 'C' << '\n' << 'G' << 'C' << 'A' << '\n' << 'G' << 'C' << 'G' << endl;
  else if (z == 'R')
        cout << 'C' << 'G' << 'T' << '\n' << 'C' << 'G' << 'C' << '\n' << 'C' << 'G' << 'A' << '\n' << 'C' << 'G' << 'G' << '\n' << 'A' << 'G' << 'A' << '\n' << 'A' << 'G' << 'G' << endl;
  else
    cout << '?' << endl;
}

int main()
{
cout << x('A') << endl;
cout << x('r') << endl;
cout << x('m') << endl;
return 0;
}
```

Comment: what is the error? Give the exact error.

Comment: How about reading a good C++ book/tutorial before asking trivial questions?

Comment: "I'm avoiding using strings for a reason". Care to share?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You declare the `x()` function to return `void`, yet you're trying to print its return value using `std::cout`.

Answer (score 1):

noYou are not returning nothing from function `x()`. Function is returning void. You are printing inside the function `x` itself. So what you need is this

```
int main()
{
  x('A') ;
  x('r') ;
  x('m') ;
  return 0;
}
```